# Proof that set $\{0, 1\}^{*}$ of all bit strings are countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I can't seem to solve this question, I found similar questions, but I wouldn't consider them exactly the same. Struggle to understand what the asterix means in this situation?

Comment: To be clear, the set of finite length bit-strings is indeed countable.  If you allow infinite-length bit strings then the set is no longer countable.  "*Struggle to understand what the asterisk means in this situation*"  That is the [Kleene Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), and means we are looking at the set of finite length strings creatable using elements of the set in question.  So, $\{0,1\}^* = \{\varepsilon,0,1,00,01,10,11,000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111,0000,\dots\}$

Comment: As for proving it is countable, my starting to write out the set fully above should be a very clear hint as to how to proceed.